# MYSQL order by datetime

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I need to select one row with the "highest" date and time from a table, but I can't get the highest one, the ORDER BY DESC doesn't work.
Here's my query:

```
SELECT count(*) as c, 
       start, 
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) as S, 
       duration
  FROM appuntamento
 WHERE DATE(start) = DATE('2014-04-08 18:30:00') 
 ORDER BY S DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

I don't care about getting the start value in unix timestamp, it was the nth try to get through this

Any tips?

Comment: can you provide the sample dataset and your table definition using http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: why dont you just do MAX(start) in your select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems here.  First, the presence of `COUNT(*)` turns this into an aggregate query, which do you not want. That's probably the cause of your trouble.

Second, if you have a lot of rows in your `appuntamento` table the performance of this query will be bad, because you can't use an index.

Presuming that you want the time and duration of the last (latest-in-time) row from a particular day in your table, and the number of appointments for that same day, you need to do this:

```
 SELECT a.start, a.duration, b.count
   FROM (
         SELECT start,
                duration
           FROM appuntamento
          WHERE start >= DATE('2014-04-08 18:30:00')
            AND start < DATE('2014-04-08 18:30:00') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
          ORDER BY start DESC, duration DESC
          LIMIT 1
        ) AS a
    JOIN (
         SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
           FROM appuntamento
          WHERE start >= DATE('2014-04-08 18:30:00')
            AND start < DATE('2014-04-08 18:30:00') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
         ) AS b
```

Explanation: First, this form of searching on `start` allows you to use an index on the `start` column. You want that for performance reasons.

```
          WHERE start >= DATE('2014-04-08 18:30:00')
            AND start < DATE('2014-04-08 18:30:00') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Second, you need to handle the COUNT(*) as a separate subquery. I have done that.

Third, you can definitely do `ORDER BY start DESC` and it will work if `start` is a DATETIME column. No need for `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

Fourth, I used `ORDER BY start DESC, duration DESC` to arrange to return the longest appointment if there happen to  be several with the same `start` time.

Answer (score 0):

if all you want is one row returned then use the MAX() function without the order. should do the trick.

```
SELECT count(*) as c, 
       MAX(start) as highest_date, 
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) as S, 
       duration
  FROM appuntamento
 WHERE DATE(start) = DATE('2014-04-08 18:30:00')
```

---

also with your order by statement. you need to add a group by so that you aren't combining incorrect rows with the COUNT() aggregate.

```
 SELECT count(*) as c, 
       start, 
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) as S, 
       duration
 FROM appuntamento
 WHERE DATE(start) = DATE('2014-04-08 18:30:00') 
 GROUP BY S
 ORDER BY S DESC 
 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: and if you want to remove the timestamp and just get the "highest" date then do MAX(DATE(start))